# Using Selenium for Python Scripting

Tags: python, selenium, browser, scripting

I have written a `Python` code to open my gmail account. Here is the code that I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.gmail.com')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
emailElem.send_keys(myemail)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
emailElem.send_keys(mypassword)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit')
emailElem.submit()
```

Everything is working fine. I have also found out that there are sites that lets one `Log In` only after entering a `Captcha`, to prevent scripts from logging in.

**Is there a way in which I can use my above code get around this problem??**

Comment: The _entire point_ of captchas is to prevent what you're doing, so I kind of doubt there's a simple way around it...

Comment: Is your question about gmail specifically, or other sites in general?

Comment: My question is for any site, not just gmail

Answer (score 0):

Experimentation. If the site is not showing a captcha to normal users you'll have to mimic being a human with your code. So that could mean that you use `time.sleep(x)` to make it seem like it takes a while before certain actions happen.

Otherwise there are services out there that solve captchas for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the same actions repetitively, gmail(or any other site which tries to block automation) will identify your actions as automated ones. To get around this you need to pass random sleep time in your script. Also, switching between multiple credential helps.

Answer (score 0):

For that you must used some Captcha resolver API. Here I will provide you website which provide text code of captcha https://2captcha.com/